# Pass an Array to Static Method of Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and I have a need to pass an associative array to a static function in an eloquent model.

```
class MyClass extends Eloquent\Model
{
    static function scopeRegister($input) {
        return $input['key1'];
    }
}
```

Running with Tinker, here is my input:

```
$input = array('key1'=>'value', 'key2'=>'value', 'key3'=> 'value', 'key4'=>'value');
```

When I try it, though, I'm getting an error:

> PHP error:  Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as array

And when I type-hint array:

```
class MyClass extends Eloquent\Model
{
    static function scopeRegister(array $input) {
        return $input['key1'];
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\KeywordGeotarget::scopeRegister() must be of the type array, object given

What's happening here and how can I access the values defined in the array from the static method within the model?

---

EDIT: I'm just using tinker right now to test this but here is the code I'm using to call the method:

```
php artisan tinker
>> $input = array('key1'=>'value','key2'=>'value','key3'=>'value', 'key4'=>'value');
>> App\MyClass::register($input);
```

Comment: can you show us where (the code) you are calling the static method?

Comment: plz add the code in which you are calling the function.

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. I updated the question and added the code in which I'm calling the function.

Comment: For what it's worth my above statement was not intended to be sarcastic (after revisiting it I feel like it could be interpreted as being sarcastic). I was being sincere - thank you both for reading my question, as your comments directed me to provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining an eloquent scope. Scopes do not work with arrays, but with queries.

You can read more about how to declare and use scopes here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes

If you want to call `register()` like you did in the tinker example, do this instead (just remove the scope):

```
class MyClass extends Eloquent\Model
{
    static function register(array $input) {
        return $input['key1'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I removed scope and it's working. For some reason I was thinking that I needed to use a scope in order to use a static method :/ Marking this as the correct answer because of the link to the documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a scope, you need to add a `$query` as the first parameter and then do something like this:

```
static function scopeRegister($query, array $input)
{
    return $query->where($input['key1']);
}
```

If you just want to have a method and you don't want to use it as a local scope, just rename the method (remove `scope` part):

```
static function register(array $input)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I removed scope and it's working. For some reason I was thinking that I needed to use a scope in order to use a static method :/

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding for the adding query scope is wrong I guess you need to go through documentation I think. [Check it over here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes)
The scopes represents the query builder properties and you can't get builder class properties as array. You should use it like this.

```
class MyClass extends Eloquent\Model
{
    public function scopeRegister($query) {

        return $query->where(// perform your where here);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and for showing the correct usage.